# Help with LOBPCG algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to implement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOBPCG to find the largest eigenvalue (and a corresponding eigenvector) of my matrix

$A=\begin{pmatrix} 
139166.135& 129188.844& 113043.938&      0.000 \\
129188.844& 122554.673& 109691.588&      0.000 \\
113043.938& 109691.588& 101227.755&      0.000 \\
     0.000&      0.000&      0.000&      0.000 \end{pmatrix}$

As I understand, B and T are identities, so I can "ignore" them. I set the initial $x = (1,0,0,0)^T$. My first iteration goes like this:

$rayl := x^TAx/x^Tx = 139166.135$

$r := Ax - rayl * x = (0, 129188.844, 113043.938, 0)^T$

$w := r$

$x := x + w = (1, 129188.844, 113043.938, 0)^T $

If I let it iterate multiple times, and normalize $x$ after each step, the $x$ does not go to any eigenvector.

**EDIT:** I implemented [Rayleigh quotient iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient_iteration) and it works very well. But it would be nice to avoid matrix inversion.

Comment: What happens when you try other initial vectors?

Comment: It converges to other vectors. Still, not eigenvectors.

Comment: How are you selecting your step size parameter $\alpha$?

Comment: As you see above, it is 1. I tried different values, and it still converges to the same vector.

Comment: Steepest ascent with a fixed step size isn't guaranteed to converge unless the step size is sufficiently small.  In this case, it appears that $\alpha=1$ is far too large (try $\alpha=1 \times 10^{-8}$ instead.)  You really want to implement a locally optimal version of the algorithm or better yet a three-term version.